# How can I learn a DirectShow programming?

Tags: c#, c++, directshow, video-capture, directshow.net

I'm a .Net C# Developer. I want to develop the media programming about video/audio codec, capture media from source, etc. I'm going to use the DirectShow Lib, but I read it on MSDN, and I'm very confused, because I'm a beginner.

Do you have the best tutorials or some article that can make beginner understand to program in the DirectShow architecture? If so, please share them.

Answer (score 5):

You will find these useful:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/PrgmngDirectShowappsCS.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directshowmediaplayer.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directshownet.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/MPEG2_Capture_Device.aspx

Oh and these too:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/dshowencoder.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/rendering.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/samplegrabberfilter-wm6.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Tanvon_DirectShowFilters.aspx

Hope that helps.

Regards

Richard

Answer (score 2):

Dude, IMO It's better develop direct show in C++, you just should learn how to create COM object and uninitialize it, C++ is faster, and current available library of direct show all are in c++, cases which are in code project in c# are good for learning basic of direct show, but they aren't practical solutions. they are COM wrapper to use them in C#, the speed is main concern and their speed in real time video analyzing is not good. the MSDN is best reference for working with directshow and there are good samples in SDK

Comment: I agree, the samples in combination with the MSDN documentation are a good way to learn DirectShow. I also found the MS DirectShow forum to be very helpful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/threads though this forum provides no support for .NET

Answer (score 0):

Just read DirectShow SDK in MSDN from beginning. Then install [GraphEditPlus](http://www.infognition.com/GraphEditPlus), try building some graphs and then from File menu you can generate C# code which builds these graphs using DirectShowLib for .NET and see how it does it.